# Add inline style using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, innerhtml

I'm attempting to add this code to a dynamically created div element

```
style = "width:330px;float:left;"
```

The code in which creates the dynamic `div` is

```
var nFilter = document.createElement('div');
nFilter.className = 'well';
nFilter.innerHTML = '<label>' + sSearchStr + '</label>';
```

My idea is to add the style after `< div class="well"` but i don't know how i'd do it.

Comment: What difference does it make? Inline style will always have the highest specificity.

Comment: because the div is dynamically created, i can't use static since it's a complete Javascript library script

Comment: Maybe this is an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve? Is `nFilter.style.width = '330px'; nFilter.style.float = 'left';` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

```
nFilter.style.width = '330px';
nFilter.style.float = 'left';
```

This should add an inline style to the element.

Most CSS names are mapped 1:1 to the JavaScript property. CSS properties with dashes in their names are converted to camel case. For more information see the blue information box at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Answer (score 54):

You can do it directly on the style:

```
var nFilter = document.createElement('div');
nFilter.className = 'well';
nFilter.innerHTML = '<label>'+sSearchStr+'</label>';

// Css styling
nFilter.style.width = "330px";
nFilter.style.float = "left";

// or
nFilter.setAttribute("style", "width:330px;float:left;");
```

Comment: Not the CSS styling but the third option with setAttribute worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 25):

Using jQuery :

```
$(nFilter).attr("style","whatever");
```

Otherwise :

```
nFilter.setAttribute("style", "whatever");
```

should work

Comment: It is unnecessary to use JQuery in this case

Comment: He gives an alternate solution without JQuery. Don't see the need for a downvote.

Answer (score 16):

You can try with this

```
nFilter.style.cssText = 'width:330px;float:left;';
```

That should do it for you.

Answer (score 13):

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('style', 'width:330px; float:left');
div.setAttribute('class', 'well');
var label = document.createElement('label');
label.innerHTML = 'YOUR TEXT HERE';
div.appendChild(label);
```

Answer (score 12):

A few people have an example using setAttribute which I like. However it assumes you don't have any styles currently set. I would maybe do something like:

```
nFilter.setAttribute('style', nFilter.getAttribute('style') + ';width:330px;float:left;');
```

Or make it into a helper function like this:

```
function setStyle(el, css){
  el.setAttribute('style', el.getAttribute('style') + ';' + css);
}

setStyle(nFilter, 'width:330px;float:left;');
```

This makes sure that you can add styles to it continuously and it won't remove any style currently set by always appending to the current styles. It also adds an extra semi colon so that if there is a style ever missing one it will append another to make sure it is fully delimited.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to add each css property line by line, you can do something like this:

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','<div id="div"></div>');

/**
 * Add styles to DOM element
 * @element DOM element
 * @styles object with css styles
 */
function addStyles(element,styles){
  for(id in styles){
    element.style[id] = styles[id];
  }
}

// usage
var nFilter = document.getElementById('div');
var styles = {
  color: "red"
  ,width: "100px"
  ,height: "100px"
  ,display: "block"
  ,border: "1px solid blue"
}
addStyles(nFilter,styles);
```

Comment: this is so cool, it helps me a lot with organizing my plain html css code without framework. thanks a tons!

Answer (score 4):

you should make a css class `.my_style` then use `.addClass('.mystyle')`

Comment: I use `element.classList.add("myClass")`, it works, is it what you meant? It drives my source code a lot easier to maintain and to understand than other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [cssText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration)

```
nFilter.style.cssText +=';width:330px;float:left;';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
document.getElementById("vid-holder").style.width=300 + "px";
```

Answer (score -1):

Fantastic solution by stuyam
I am adding to that

```
addStyle('img', 'height:auto;max-width:98%;');


function addStyle(elem, cssText) {

 let curstyle;
 
 const arr = document.querySelectorAll(elem);
 
 arr.forEach(function(el){
    // get and save any current image styles
    curstyle = el.getAttribute("style");
    
    if(curstyle){
       curstyle = curstyle.trim();
        // make sure right most character of [curstyle] is [;]
       let lastchr = curstyle.charAt(curstyle.length - 1);
       
       if(lastchr !== ";"){
           curstyle += ";";
       }
    }else{
       curstyle = "";
    }

   el.style.cssText += cssText;
   console.log(el.style.cssText);
 });
}
```