# Add inline style using Javascript to divs created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating dynamically divs using javascript. I want to assign the style to none.

**style="display: none;"**

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753147/add-inline-style-using-javascript), I can to do this with the following options

```
 publishcontent.style.display="none";
 publishcontent.setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
```

But this isn't working. This is the way I created the divs. No way of the options I found is working. If I edit the html with firebug and type **style="display: none;"** it works.

This is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/reric/1) showing the example.

```
publishpaging=document.createElement("div");
var name="df"+counterName;
publishpaging.id=name;
counterName=counterName+1;
arrayNames.push(name);
counter++;
publishcontent=document.createElement("div");//"<div class='bonecardSmall'></div>";
publishcontent.className = "bonecardSmallP";
publishcontent.id=index.id;
if(arrayNames.length > 1){
    //publishpaging.style.display="none";
    publishpaging.setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
}
publishpaging.appendChild(publishcontent);
```

Comment: are you sure that the if condition is true

Comment: yes, it is inside a for, there's the jsbin showing the loop

Comment: I think you want to check `arrayNames.length > 0` your jsbin is showing arrayNames.length is 1. So this condition will not be true.

Comment: I have a loop from  0 to 12. Each time I do arrayNames.push(name) the length will be greater that 1 after the first iteration. That's not the issue

Comment: you just want to hide it? http://jsbin.com/yibeqoqa/1/edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"name" variable  stores the id of publishcontent so use it in jquery

```
 $('#'+name).css('display','none');
```

Comment: The OP already has a reference to the element as *publishpaging*, so the property can be set directly. The jQuery should be `$(publishpaging).css('display','none')` at least. However, that is very inefficient, there's no reason why `publishcontent.style.display = 'none'` should not work.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery, just use:

```
$('div').css('display','none');
```

Comment: it doesn't work
$(publishcontent).css('display','none');

Comment: @Diego where is the newly added div appended? what is the id or class of the parent element?

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery try this,

```
$('yourdivtagid').css('display','none')
```

Comment: No he just mentioned $('div'). I think he should use div tag id.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply hide using jquery hide function.

```
$("#"+ name).hide();
```