# Css code inside JS file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I remember from somewhere some simple way to use `css` code inside JS file, but can't remember how exactly.

Obviously simply putting the `css` code inside JS file won't work, I guess there's a need for some comments or something like that.

*Note: I don't want to use JS to render a `<link...>` for a `css` file. I want load JS file normally with `<script...>` and inside a `*.js` file I want include pure `css` code, as it would appear normally in `*.css` file.

Comment: You can add `<style>` tags to DOM and add styles into it?

Comment: I'm not looking for inlining `css`, @Arpit Goyal

Comment: You're looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753147/add-inline-style-using-javascript

Comment: Are you all skipping the `*Note` in the post above?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#id").css("parameter","property");
```

example..

```
$("#id").css("border","1px solid");
```

for multiple css..

```
$("#id").css({
   'font-size' : '10px',
   'width' : '30px',
   'height' : '10px'
});
```

better to use

> addClass( )

function.. for multiple css property..

Comment: It doesn't related to the question, @Pikachu

Comment: document.write('<link href="../css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>');
You use this line for adding whole css file using JS in *.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Nice little function to add Internal CSS Block to document

```
function createStyleNode(cssText, options, doc) {
    doc = doc || document;
    var style = doc.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    if(options && options.id){
        style.id = options.id;
    }
    if (style.styleSheet){
        style.styleSheet.cssText = cssText;
    } else {
        style.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(cssText));
    }
    return style;
}


cssText = 'body {color: red}';
head.appendChild(createStyleNode(cssText, {'id': 'stylesFromJS'}));
```

Adding Ids will be useful, if you are planning to delete / replace them later from JS.

Comment: It doesn't related to the question, @Arpit Goyal

Comment: @uhrr please make the question a but more clear, either you want inline styles or internal styles, both answers are there, the approach can only be changed.

Comment: External styles. Inside the `*.js` file, @Arpit Goyal  Take a look at the `*Note` in my post

Comment: It says: I don't want to use JS to render a <link...> for a css file.  which is what external styling is. Read http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Hm. What I meant is: I don't want to use JS code, to build a `<link>` element. If that could be confusing, the next thing isn't: I need a `css` code to be read from `*.js` file.