# How to change the style of another element inline using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change the style of another inside a html element using javascript.

I have used the below code to change the current html element.

```
<p onmouseover="this.style.color = 'black;">This text should be changed</p>
<h1>How to change this element when hovered on p element</h1>
```

I would like to change the other element's style inside the p tag using javascript.

can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add inline style using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753147/add-inline-style-using-javascript)

Comment: not clear with the question...

Comment: why use js simple use with css `p:hover + h1{"add your style}`

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS you can achieve the same

```
<style>
 p:hover + h1 {
  background-color : red
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're after (not my work) - check out the fiddle link ...

```
<html>
<body>
    <span id="div1" style="color:black;" onmouseover="stext()" onmouseout="htext()">TEXT1</span><p />
    <hr color="black" />
<span id="div2" style="color:red;" onmouseover="htext()" onmouseout="stext()">Text2</span> 

</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FFCFy/16/

Answer (score 0):

for example if you want to change the color:

```
<script>
document.getElementByTagName("p").style.color = "blue";
</script>
```

that should probably bound to an event, accordingly to what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('#a-element').hover(function() {
    $('#b-element').css('background-color', 'yellow');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $('#b-element').css('background-color', '');
  });
});
```

If #b comes immediately after #a, the simplest solution is in pure css:

```
#a:hover + #b {
    background: #ccc
}
```

If between #a and #b are other elements, you have to use ~ like this:

```
#a:hover ~ #b {
    background: #ccc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="color:red;" onmouseover="ch(event)">This text should be changed</p>
    <h1>How to change this element when hovered on p element</h1>

    <script>
        function ch(e) {
            e.target.style.color = "black";
            alert();
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**use with Javascript**

```js
function change(that){
document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].style.color="red";
  
  }
```

```html
<p onmouseover="change()">This text should be changed</p>
<h1>How to change this element when hovered on p element</h1>
```

**use with css**

```css
p:hover + h1{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<p >This text should be changed</p>
<h1>How to change this element when hovered on p element</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("p").mouseover(function(){
   jQuery("h1").css("color", "yellow");
});
```