# How to add inline style in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("usersList").innerHTML.style="background-color:red" += "<th>" + newuser + "</th>";
```

With this syntax I am not able to get the `background-color` of my `table rows`.

Could you please give me the valid syntax to my question?

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753147/add-inline-style-using-javascript).

Comment: Duplicate of [Add inline style using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753147/add-inline-style-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

These are two different statements, also style is not a prpoerty on `.innerHTML` but on the element itself.

Also it is not a great idea to overwrite the complete style attribute, instead set the specific properties.

```
document.getElementById("usersList").style.backgroundColor="red";    
document.getElementById("usersList").innerHTML += "<th>" + newuser + "</th>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to add style

```
document.getElementById("usersList").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing these two points:

- `backgroundColor` is applied to the `style` property of the element
- `innerHTML` is used to add HTML content in the element.

```js
var newuser = 'someUser';
document.getElementById("usersList").style.backgroundColor="red";    
document.getElementById("usersList").innerHTML += "<th>" + newuser + "</th>";
```

```html
<table id='usersList' border='1'></table>
```