# Call javascript function from style inside div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to call javascript function in `left prop` from `style` inside `div` tag.

```js
function setLeft() {
        return '15px';
    }
```

```html
<div class="configValue" style="position: absolute; left: setLeft()">
  <strong>
   @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.First().ConfigurationValue)
  </strong>
</div>
```

I tried also something like this, but did not work:

```
"javascript:setLeft();"
```

Comment: you cannot do this, but you can change left prop by script in js

Comment: You can't. However you *can* invoke a function after the page loads and [edit the style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753147/add-inline-style-using-javascript) there.

Comment: A way of doing this would be: 1. `style="position: absolute; left:var(--left)"` and 2. use a javascript function to set the `--left`variable: `yourElement.style.setProperty("--left", "15px");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. However, you could change the style from JS though.

```
var configValue = document.querySelector('.configValue');
configValue.style.left = setLeft();
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use jQuery to add an attribute?

```
<div class="configValue" style="position: absolute" onload="setleft()">
```

jQuery:

```
function setleft(){
    $(this).css(left:"15px");
}
```

This should work. Maybe my syntax is wrong though, haven't done web development in a while