# how to add CSS for a innerhtml in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

in my innerhtml, i have pass and fail and i want to add css properties for these.

```js
function display()
{
    var a=document.getElementById("myList");
    var dropdownvalue = a.options [a.selectedIndex].text;
    var b=document.getElementById("myText").value;

    if(dropdownvalue == b.substring(0,4)) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Pass"; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Fail";  
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753147/add-inline-style-using-javascript

Comment: yeah, thank for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use .style

```
if(dropdownvalue == b.substring(0,4)) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Pass"; 
        document.getElementById("result").style.color = "green";
     }
        else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=    "Fail";  
        document.getElementById("result").style.color = "red";
     }
```

Comment for any questions :)