# How to add Mathrandom to a class

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

New to Javascript here. This is my first probject that I am attempting. My goal is to add math.random to a class inside my CSS file to make random raindrops appear and go across different parts of my screen for the animation.

I tried googling how to add math.random to a class and cannot find anything. How do I do it? I just need a general idea so I can play around with what works. Thank you!

```html
<body>
  <div class="rain">
    <div class="rain-container">
      <div class="rain-drop drop1"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop2"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop3"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop4"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop5"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop6"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop7"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop8"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop9"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop10"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop11"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop12"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop13"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop14"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop15"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop16"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop17"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop18"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop19"></div>
      <div class="rain-drop drop20"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```js
const rainDrop = document.querySelectorAll(".rain-drop");
const mathRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);

// function raining() {}

function randomRain() {

}

console.log(rainDrop);
```

```css
.rain {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
}

.rain-drop {
    position: relative;
    width: 1px;
    border-left: .125vw solid rgb(189, 182, 182);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    // right: 50vw;
    // height: .5vh;
}

.rain-container {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    top: 100%;

}

.rain-container {
    animation: drop 2.5s linear -12s infinite normal;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
}

@keyframes drop {
        0% {
            top: 0vh;
        }

        50% {
            top: 50vh;
        }

        100% {
            top: 100vh;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't add math.random inside a css file, you can use inline styles in HTML with javascript

you can use something like this:

```js
const drops = document.querySelectorAll(".rain-drop")

drops.forEach(drop => {
  // drop.style.property = value;
  drop.style.top = ( Math.random() * 200 ) + "px";
  drop.style.left = ( Math.random() * 200 ) + "px"
})
```

also check this answer might be useful: [Add inline style using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753147/add-inline-style-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This function will asign a random hexadecimal color to your html element when click a button

```js
var genNew = document.getElementById("boton");
var element = document.querySelector(".myElement");

const setBg = () => {
  const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  element.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
}

genNew.addEventListener("click", setBg, false);

setBg();
```

```html
<div class="myElement">Element</div>
<button id="boton"> Go! </button>
```