# Styling the HTML tags that are created in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

If i use HTML tags inside javascript file, how can i select them and use them in a css file?

for example:
javascript:
`<li id="id"> name </li>`

how can i select and use id in the stylesheet?

I tried it this way but it didnt work
#id li { background: red;}

Comment: `#id { background: red;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using ids as they have to be unique (no more than one per page). If you have to target specific list items use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

```css
ul li[data-type="name"] { color: red; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-type="name">Bobby</li>
  <li data-type="age">26</li>
</ul
```

Answer (score 0):

either you can use the JS also add style to the Element.

`document.getElementById(id).style.property = new style`

[Add inline style using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753147/add-inline-style-using-javascript)

Or you need to load the `script` before the `style`.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a id to any tag or element you don't need to use element or tag name to style it. Directly use id. by `#id li { background: red; }` it means inside the element(which has id) it search for another li element.
Try

```
#id {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your creating element dynamically it's better to apple style that time
for example

```
var el = document.createElement('div');

el.setAttribute(
 'style',
 'background-color: red; color: white; width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 1px red solid');
 var container = document.getElementById('container-id');
 container.appendChild(el);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using ids as they have to be unique

```css
.bgred { background: red;color:#fff }
.bggreen { background: green;color:#fff }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="bgred">Bobby</li>
  <li class="bggreen">26</li>
</ul>
```