Why do browsers only complain about specific types of inline-styles?
I have a CSP that I want to remove unsafe-inline from the style-src. Part of this process is to remove all inline styles from a javascript file. When checking the console logs in the browsers, I see all browsers i tested, Chrome, Safari, Opera, Firefox, and Edge, only complained about inline styles like the below line.
h.setAttribute('style', 'visibility: hidden;position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -999px;');

But it won't complain about this line. From my understanding the below is still an inline style, but the difference it uses a javascript style property assignment.
s.style.fontSize = "12px";

I wanted some confirmation that i'm right since im not 100% sure and if anyone has a better understanding of this and can explain why it's not complaining that would be amazing. I tried searching online for this, but I haven't seen any resources explaining this.
EDIT: Below is the console log error i see in chrome
file.js?ts=1731118161084:51 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://cdn.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Aq7e5LGf4kZTmyqS7SqWaWXFaN/dvBB41GlMIGE1TF8='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.
EDIT 2: Corrected 12px to "12px". I mistyped this when writing the question. s.style.fontSize = "12px"; is how it appears in my javascript.
EDIT 3: Added reproducible example. I could not reproduce it using stackoverflow's snippet feature. So here's the html and you can run it in a html editor and should get the error log in your browser.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Minimal CSP Example</title>
    <!-- Content Security Policy inside the head -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'self';">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hidden-element">This is a hidden element</div>

    <script>
        // This line will trigger a CSP error because of the inline style
        const h = document.getElementById('hidden-element');
       h.setAttribute('style', 'visibility: visible');
    </script>
</body>
</html>

You can then replace the inline style with
        h.style.visibility = "visible";

And you should not see the error log anymore. I used w3schools html editor.

Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

The complaint may come from the CSS style parser, so assigning directly to the style property bypasses that check.

s.style.fontSize = 12px; is not a valid setter. "12px" needs to be in quotes.

Thank you for including the code - I can now see the 'complaint' you describe.

You have added 'self' as a CSP property. This property only allows style files from the same domain. If you want to make changes inline, you need to add 'unsafe-inline' as well. You can review the document in detail. I am adding an example below of how both can be used at the same time. I am changing the background color.


        const h = document.getElementById('hidden-element');
       h.setAttribute("style", "background-color: green;");
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Minimal CSP Example</title>
    <!-- Content Security Policy inside the head -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hidden-element">This is a hidden element</div>
</body>
</html>




I am not using a style file though nor do I want to. I want all my css within my javascript fie. I also want to remove the use of unsafe-inline from my CSP. I noticed that using h.style.visibility = "visible"; instead of h.setAttribute('style', 'visibility: visible'); does not return an error log in the console. What I want to know is why that is. Also, your example causes an error when trying to apply the CSP and the CSP is being ignored

The console error here is because we are running it in stackoverflow. I didn't get that error when I run the file I created in w3schools html editor or local computer editor. The setAttribute("style", ...) statement is accepted as an inline style definition, so you get an error when you don't add 'unsafe-inline'. However, the h.style... statement is not an inline style definition, it is a change with js and is not blocked by CSP. @CrisManrique

I thought it was considered an inline-style? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753147/add-inline-style-using-javascript Even the accepted answer on this post says it applies an inline style. Maybe im misunderstanding it? @Mustafa

Then I want to explain what I understand. CSP accepts the changes made with setAttribute as inline style. Because when a change is made with this method, it removes all the style properties previously defined as inline and adds only this one. However, in the definitions we make as element.style, it changes this property with js and does not delete the existing inline style rules. For this reason, CSP sees this as harmless. @CrisManrique
